# How do I play a video based on a partial stream? 

Tags: c#, .net, video, stream

I'm getting parts (chunks..whatever) of a video file in an array of bytes,
just reading some bytes from the video and saving them into the array.
I want to play those parts while other parts are being received, like playing a video while its still buffering, and then saving all the parts into one video file.

I have no clue where to begin

The format of the videos is wmv and avi.

Comment: This is only possible for WMV if the header specifies that the file is un-indexed (unseekable). For indexed files the player will try to seek to the index which is at the very end of the file, so that wont' work.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: WPF. is there any way to save the original file with the index at the beginning? or can i send the index part first and then the rest of the parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are low that you can start playing a **file** before you have it in whole. Most container formats and associated readers/parsers require that full file is available at the initialization stage.

In some cases you still can play partial file:

- In the underlying API or parser supports progressive download/availability of data
- The file itself has the correct order of internal parts, such as index data located in the beginning of the file, so that at an early stage the reader would have the vital information available

Baiscally you have to narrow down your search to specific playback scenario with specific file formats. And alternate options is to play a sort of live stream, not exactly a file.

Comment: Its what i want, play it as live stream, but save it afterwards. somewhat like youtube...

Comment: This way you would read the file on server side and stream it over network with a sort of streaming protocol (RTSP, RTP, RTMP to name well known protocols for this purpose) and on client side you receive the data, present it and re-multiplex it back into a file if needed. You normally cannot just stream a file simply as binary data.